# The functional ODE $(x \partial_x + a x^2 - b x + 1) f(x) = f(q x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, recurrence-relations, functional-equations

I have a functional differential equation
$$\Big(\epsilon x \frac{d}{dx} + a x^2   - b x + 1\Big) f(x) = f(q x).$$
Notice that this function involves both $f(x)$ and $f(q x)$, where $q$ is some real number with $0 \leq q < 1$.  I want to solve this equation on the condition that $f(0)=1$.

**In the limit $\epsilon=0$:**

I have solved similar equations that lack a derivative term ($\epsilon = 0$) by noting that the equation constitutes a recursion relation:
$$ f(x) = \frac{f(q^N x)}{(a x^2 - b x + 1)^N}.$$
As $N \rightarrow \infty$, we have $q^N \rightarrow 0$, since $0\leq q < 1$, providing
$$ f(x) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{(a x^2 - b x + 1)^N}$$
if we note the condition $f(0)=1$. This result is actually enough to solve the problem with $\epsilon = 0$, since expansion in partial fractions gives the result as an infinite series.

**With $\epsilon\neq 0$:**

In this case a similar recursion approach can be made, but it provides an *infinite order ODE*:
$$ \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \Big(\epsilon x\frac{d}{dx}+ a x^2   - b x + 1\Big)^N f(x) = 1.$$
This is now very difficult. Does anyone have a recommendation to make progress on the problem with $\epsilon \neq 0 $ ?  One solution is to solve the problem $L^N f(x) = 1$ for arbitrary $N$, where $L$ has the obvious meaning. Limiting $N\rightarrow \infty$ would then provide the desired solution of the functional ODE.

Comment: The expression in the title contains a derivative after "$ a x ^ 2 $", while there is no such thing in the body. Also, "$ \epsilon $" appears in the body but not in the title. Please edit the post and make it the way you actually intend it to be.

Comment: And a side note: since we're not working with multivariate functions, the notation "$ \frac { \mathrm d } { \mathrm d x } $" for the derivative which is used in the body is more suitable than the notation "$ \partial _ x $" used in the title.